# New line character in c#

Tags: c#, newline

I wrote this code to count the number of characters in a text file :

```
sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
sr.DiscardBufferedData();
int Ccount = 0;
while (sr.Peek() != -1)
{
  sr.Read();
  Ccount++;
}
```

but after applying this code to a file contains :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Ccount = 30 ????
why?
I am using Windows Xp on virtual box on my Macbook 
the program used : Microsoft Visual Basic 2010.

Comment: Character + return + new line = 3 characters per line = 3 * 10 = 30 in total.

Comment: 10 chars + 10 carriage returns + 10 line feeds? `?\r\n`

Comment: Environment.NewLine should match the newline character in any OS.

Comment: Have a read of [StreamReader.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx), the StreamReader.Read method reads a single character at a time.

Comment: To get the count, you can do this (`string str = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\text.txt");
int count = str.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Windows each new line consists of two characters `\r` and `\n`. You have 10 lines, each line have 1 visible characters and 2 new line characters which add up to 30 characters.

If you have created your file in Mac or Unix/Linux you would have gotton different result (20 characters). Because Unix uses only `\n` and Mac uses only `\r` for a new line.

You can use some editors (such as Notepad++) to show you new line characters, or even switch between different modes (DOS/Unix/Mac).

Answer (score 15):

You're reading one character at a time, and each line contains three characters:

- one digit
- one carriage return (`\r`)
- one newline (`\n`)

(Windows uses `\r\n` as its newline sequence.  The fact that you're running in a VM on a Mac doesn't affect that.)

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way to do this. Make the entire *.txt file to a string array and measure it:

```
int count = 0;

string[] Text = File.ReadAllLines(/*Path to the file here*/);

for (int i = 0; i < Text.Count(); i++)
{
        count += Text[i].Length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new line is actually 2 separate characters: LF CR (line feed and carriage return). But you would know that if you put a breakpoint in your loop. Now for extra credit, how many bytes that is in unicode?

Answer (score 2):

Windows typically uses `\r\n` for new line, that is ASCII characters 0x13 and 0x10.

Suggest you prove this to yourself by doing this:

```
Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x}", sr.Read());
```